# Stuck on a PHP Contact Form

Tags: php

I have tried changing things, removing everything in the required section to see if the form will pass. I am stuck. At the moment it is only sending through the email address within the notification email. The other fields and subjects for those field dont appear in the email.

Any help appreciated.

```
<form method="post" action="contact3.php" id="contactformy">
    <input type="text" class="textbox" name="contact-name" value="Your Name*" id="contact-name" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'contact-name';}">
    <input type="text" class="textbox" name="email" value="Your E-mail*" id="email" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'email';}">
    <input name="Neighbourhood" type="text" class="Subject" value="Neighbourhood" id="neighbourhood" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'neighbourhood';}">
    </div>
    <textarea placeholder="Your Full Residential Address*" type="text" id="address" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'address';}"></textarea>
    <div class="clear"> </div>
        <input type="submit" value="SEND MESSAGE">                   
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is the PHP:

```
<?php
    if(!$_POST) exit;
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    //$error[] = preg_match('/\b[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b/i',     $_POST['email']) ? '' : 'INVALID EMAIL ADDRESS';
    if(!eregi("^[a-z0-9]+([_\\.-][a-z0-9]+)*" ."@"."([a-z0-9]+([\.-][a-z0-9]+)*)+"."\\.[a-z]{2,}"."$",$email )){
        $error.="Invalid email address entered";
        $errors=1;
    }
    if($errors==1) echo $error;
    else{
        $values = array ('contact-name','email','neighbourhood','address');
        $required = array('contact-name','email','address');

        $your_email = "lawrencesuss@gmail.com";
        $email_subject = "New Message: ".$_POST['neighbourhood'];
        $email_content = "new signup:\n";

        foreach($values as $key => $value){
            if(in_array($value,$required)){
                if ($key != 'contact-name' && $key != 'address') {
                    if( empty($_POST[$value]) ) { 
                        echo 'PLEASE FILL IN REQUIRED FIELDS';
                        exit;
                    }
                }
                $email_content .= $value.': '.$_POST[$value]."\n";
            }
        }

        if(@mail($your_email,$email_subject,$email_content)) {
            header('Location: /dankie.html'); 
        } else {
            echo 'ERROR!';
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: try changing `<input name="Neighbourhood"` to `<input name="neighbourhood"` : lower case `n`. That's causing at least one failure

Comment: I don't know if it change something but try to had header to the mail

Comment: The name you used here i.e. `contact-name` is not a valid PHP variable name as `-` is not allowed in a variable name so change it to  `name="contact_name"`

Comment: Your `<testarea>` does not have a name so it wont get passed back to PHP on the post

Comment: Your HTML is not written properly. You're closing div elements in the middle of a form element. Clean up your HTML before you try to get the form working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a var_dump($_POST) to see what exactly is being passed from your form.

And check this :

```
<input name="Neighbourhood" [...]" id="neighbourhood"
```

and in your PHP script :

```
$_POST['neighbourhood'];
```

$_POST uses name value pairs and they are case-sensitive.

Comment: THANK YOU SOOOOOOO MUCH to you all! Didnt even spot the Upper case. And making the changes suggested, worked like a charm.